# How to keep default value to the textbox in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fill some default value to the textbox, I tried below code...but unable to keep some default value. Please suggest me the solution.

.ts file:

```
loadFormDefaultContent = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl('000'), 
  });
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="loadFormDefaultContent">
    <div class="form-group row">
            <input
              id="idTest"
              [(ngModel)]="asyncTest1"
              [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
              [typeahead]="testAbc"
              (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
              (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
              class="form-control searchInput"
              placeholder="sample data"
              required
              formControlName="userName"
            />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you cant keep default value because of two way binding (asyncTest1).

Comment: `formControlName` *and* `[(ngModel)]`? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't user ngModel when using reactive forms in angular. You can set default value like below.

```
username: new FormControl("Your Data"),
OR
username: new FormControl({value: 'Your Default Data', disabled: false})
```

And your html would look use formControlName and not ngModel.

```
<input id="idTest" class="form-control searchInput" formControlName="userName" />
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-nqsktc?file=app/app.component.ts